# What duality can you quote that says supremum always exists $\implies$ infimum always exists of a bounded set?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, category-theory

Say you've proven that for a subset of the reals bounded above, there exists a supremum of the set in the reals.  How do you prove the dual version for infimum without going through all the steps again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a set which is bounded below. We want to show that $A$ has an infimum.

Let $B=\{-a\,|\,a\in A\}$. Because taking the negative reverses the direction of inequalities, $B$ is bounded above. We  can then use the fact that $B$ has a supremum to conclude that $A$ has an infimum.

Comment: But is there something in category theory that says this automatically?

Comment: Not my field! The map that takes $x$ to $-x$ reverses order, and even plays nice with the additive structure.

Answer (score 0):

If **B** is your given set, let **A**={a:a < b, for all b∈**B**}, then **A** is non-empty as it contains the lower bound of **B**, and it is bounded above by any element of **B** and hence has a supremum.You can check that this is also the infimum of **B**.

This works for any totally ordered set, i,e. supremum property implies infimum property for any totally ordered set.