# Real analysis question: Suprema and Infima

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> Let $S$ be an ordered set with the $L.U.B$ Property, $S \supset B \neq
>  \varnothing$, $B$ is bounded below. Write $L = \{ l : l \; \text{is a
>  lower bound of } \;  B \} $. Then, it follows that $\alpha = \sup L $
>   exists in $S$ and $\alpha = \inf B $.

## My Try:

**(1) $L \neq \varnothing$**: 
We are given that $B$ is bounded below which implies $L \neq \varnothing$.

**(2) $L$ is bounded above**: Let $l \in L$ be arbitrary, hence $ l \leq b $ for all $b$. In particular, every $b$ is an upper bound for $l$. It follows that $L$ is bounded above

**(3) $L$ has a L.U.B:**  follows from $S$ possess the Least Upper Bound property, $\alpha = \sup L $ exists.

**(4) $\alpha$ is a lower bound for $B$:**  If there is $y \in B$ with $y < \alpha$, then $y$ is not an upper bound of $L$, a clear contradiction since we have established above that every element of $B$ is an upper bound of $L$. Hence, $\alpha \leq x$ for all $x \in B$.

**(5) This implies $\alpha \in L$**

**(6) $\alpha$ is the G.L.B (infimum) of $B$.** Suppose $\beta$ is another arbitrary lower bound of $B$ with $\alpha  < \beta$. I need to show that $\beta$ is not a lower bound of $B$: $\beta \notin L$. This is true since any number greater than the supremum of $L$ is not in $L$ and we have $\alpha < \beta$.

Comment: Looks OK to me. I took the liberty of setting out the steps a little more clearly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one question to see if I have understood the concept. This problem in fact shows that $S$ also has the greatest lower bound property. Correct?

Comment: Yes, the two are equivalent. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470895/what-duality-can-you-quote-that-says-supremum-always-exists-implies-infimum-a